# Compute the following limit on the basis of $f'(0)$

Tags: limits

Compute the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)+f(2x)-2f(x)}{x}$$ on the basis of $$f'(0)$$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz It was a mistake, the fist one is f(2x), thanks for the help !

Comment: What does *on the basis of $f'(0)$* mean?

Comment: So what about $f(x)-2f(x)$? Is not it equal to $-f(x)$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang it means the answer of the compute can be written only using f'(0) ( sorry ain't an english speaker :)) )

Comment: @MostafaAyaz It is !!!

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  In English we might say *in terms of $f'(0)$*.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)+f(2x)-2f(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}+\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{x}-2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\\
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}+2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x-0}-2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

Now, each of the limits if $f'(0)$.

**Note:**$f(x)+f(2x)-2f(x)=f(2x)-f(x)$. If you use this, it simplifies a tiny bit the computations.

**P.S.** You camn also simply observe that setting $g(x)=f(x)+f(2x)-2f(x)$, then your limit simply becomes the definition of $g'(0)$.

Comment: Your one bracket should be $2\lim_{x\to 0} (f(2x)-f(0))/(2x-0),$ not $\frac{1}{2}$ times the limit term.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou TY, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}=  2(\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x-0})- \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\\$

As $x$ tends to zero, both $\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x-0}$ and $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ tend to $f'(0)$ and so $\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}$ also tends to $f'(0)$.